# How can i select a checkbox by default? <mat-list-option>, Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following HTML component:

```
<mat-selection-list #shoes>
  <mat-list-option  *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes">
    {{shoe.title}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>

<pre>
  Options selected: {{this.result | json}}
</pre>
```

And this is the ts component, which contains an array with the data sent to the HTML component.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.typesOfShoes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Aaa',
    checked: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Bbb',
    checked: false,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Ccc',
    checked: true,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'Ddd',
    checked: false,
  },
];
}
```

I leave a link to the project in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s2hqse-csv4qs?file=app/list-selection-example.ts)

[image]

Comment: I don't find anything similar in the documentation [link](https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Per Docs](https://material.angular.io/components/list/api#MatListOption)

mat-list-option has a selected property you can assign a boolean to.

So something like this should work.

```
<mat-selection-list #shoes>
  <mat-list-option  *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes" [selected]="shoe.checked">
    {{shoe.title}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

Comment: How to update "shoe.checked" when we uncheck

Comment: If you check out the docs out here https://material.angular.io/components/list/api#MatSelectionList. The mat-selection-list has an output EventEmitter "selectionChange". You could use that to track and update what is being checked or unchecked.